# Making an image view with the ability to swipe to a next image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I can not show the pictures because I don't have enough reputation but I am trying to have an imageview within the view that has a series of pictures that you can swipe to transition from one image to the next. But the only thing changing being the image in the image view, not the entire view.

[image]
[image]

I think it is similar to this question on stack overflow
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150636/swipable-image-view)

I understand the gesture part and it works but it doesn't animate like i would like it too. I want it to work like when you're swiping through photos on the photos app. Any help?

This is the code I have but I think I just need to make the image view the subview

```
#import "PizzaViewController.h"

@interface PizzaViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imgArray;
@end

@implementation PizzaViewController
@synthesize imgArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"recipe instructions 1-01.png",@"recipe instructions 2-01.png",@"recipe instructions 3-01.png", nil];
    indexToShow = 0;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRight;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureLeft;
    gestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
    gestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    [gestureLeft setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRight];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureLeft];
    self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexToShow]];
}

- (void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        if ((indexToShow-1) < -1) {
            indexToShow = imgArray.count-1;
        }
        self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexToShow]];
        indexToShow--;
    }
}

- (void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        if ((indexToShow+1) > imgArray.count ) {
            indexToShow = 0;
        }
        self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexToShow]];
        indexToShow++;
    }
}
```

@end

Comment: You have to use scrollView and place all your imageview's inside scrollView.

Comment: You can use SwipeGestureRecognizer on your view or imageview. I did the same thing in one f my projects and its working perfectly well.

Comment: Did my code work for you?

Comment: No. Sorry that's not what I was asking.

Comment: Then what is the issue? My code would allow for the subview to change but not the superview. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I would up vote yours because it did help(but I don't have the rep to do so). But i haven't gotten to the solution I want entirely. Thanks for the help and sorry for being difficult. I edited my question a little more if you could still help me.

Comment: I don't understand how my code didn't help you. If you don't want to be able to change just the image view with swiping then what do you want?

Comment: "I understand the gesture part and it works but it doesn't animate like i would like it too. I want it to work like when you're swiping through photos on the photos app". I did some more research and I think i might have to use the panGesture, or scrollview

Comment: Oh well to do it like in photos you would need a UIScrollView and put the images into that.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try it, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: @tnek316, I think I have answered your question: to make it move like in photos you will need to put the UImageView into a UIScrollView. Please select my answer and vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

To make it move like in photos you will need to put the UImageView into a UIScrollView

If you don't want it to move like photos do this:

Make an `NSArray` that contains `UImage`s. Create an int that will be the index of the image in the array that you want to show. Have it so the gesture recognizer changes an int value (when swipe right increase by one, when swipe left decrease by one). And after each swipe change the image in the `UImageView` to the object at the index of the int value.

Code example:

Setting the array

```
- (void) setImages
{
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
        UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
        UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
        UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"];
        UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"];
        UIImage *image8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"];

        NSArray *pictuesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, nil];
self.pictures = pictuesArray;

}
```

Back and next buttons

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.arrayPosition > 0) {
        self.arrayPosition--;
        [self.image setImage:[self.pictures objectAtIndex:self.arrayPosition]];
    }

}

- (IBAction)nextButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.arrayPosition < self.pictures.count - 1){
        self.arrayPosition++;
        [self.image setImage:[self.pictures objectAtIndex:self.arrayPosition]];
    }
}

self.pictures //is an array of the images
self.arrayPosition //is the index
self.image //is the UImageView
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Elaborate more with code example.

Comment: I think a `UIScrollView` is a more native and better solution. Plus it will handle the animations better.

Comment: No i Understand that completely but thanks Wyatt. I will edit now

Comment: I added an example to my code. This is a very easy and basic way to it.